# xsd one or more elements

Tags: java, xsd

Can somebody give me solution, I need one or more elements to be selected from input data
for eg:  I have input conataining 6 elements  A, B,C,D,E,F
  I can get  any one of them  or any two of them but  not in order
eg : in message 1)  I can get A
     in message 2)  I can get  D ,B

thought of xsd:choice but that selects only one element , so for first message this works fine
when I get second message It won't work
what would be the better alternative
I tried with xsd:all but didn't work

Comment: your question is vague and confusing, but i imagine you want to use a `sequence`.

Comment: <sequence> expects all the elements to be present in the message my input messages consists either one of those elements are any two of them. Hence my xsd should be able to parse the element whenever there is only one  eg: A    or whenever  multiple elements present eg:  D,B

Comment: my xsd is like this <xsd:complexType> <xsd:all >  <xsd:element name="A" type="xsd:string"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>        <xsd:element name="B" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>   <xsd:element name="C" type="xsd:string"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>  <xsd:element name="D" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/> <xsd:element name="E" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/> <xsd:element name="F" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/> </xsd:all>  </xsd:complexType>   and the input message like this  ---- 'D'B'  or just 'A'

Comment: Please edit your question to include (a) the XSD you added to a comment and (b) more thorough examples of valid and invalid combinations of ABCDEF.

Comment: sequence doesn't expect anything except order.  the min/max occurs of the elements control whether or not they are required.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements are unclear.  You might be able to achieve your desired results via

```
<xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xsd:element name="A" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="B" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="C" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="D" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="E" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="F" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:choice>
```

which would allow unlimited numbers of A through F elements in any order.

I will update this answer after you clarify your question and requirements.